# ios background task timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-task

I'm designing an app requiring sending data to server at a certain time in background mode. So I'm wondering:
Is it possible for an app to execute a piece of code 24h after I scheduled it(just once)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible if Configured schedule for the same time!! :)

Comment: `NSTimer` does not work in the background and only if you app is using on of the background modes will it be able to any thing in the background. You could use some kind of kind of background refresh of silent push notification.

Answer (score 0):

store date in  `NSUserDefaults` and further you check for 24 hours ..

```
  NSDate *date = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CONSCIENCE_START_DATE"];

if (!date) {

    // This is the 1st run of the app

    date = [NSDate date];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:date forKey:@"CONSCIENCE_START_DATE"];

}

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date];

NSLog(@"  date string = %@",str);

NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:date]; // in seconds

int numberOfHours = secondsBetween / 3600; // convert in hours

NSLog(@"There are %d hours in between the two dates.", numberOfHours);

if (numberOfHours > 24) {

    // do your code here ...

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"CONSCIENCE_START_DATE"];

}
```

hope it help you .